# The context xml file that implements the JDBCRealm enough to connect to the database?

Tags: servlets

m new to tomcat server, an I;m trying to implement jdbcRealm for FORM BASED Authentication. I have step through my codes severally as showed by the book example that I have been following, but it is still not working on my laptop. Not even the solution to the exercise given by the book.
I therefore would like to know if the context xml file that implements the jdbcRealm is  enough to connect to the database that contains the user role and login details in the schemea or I need to write a code to connect to the database for FORM Based Authentication
Thanks for your time and support

I have designed two tables in a schema; one for user role and the other for user login details (password and username).Also, I downloaded MySQl jdbc connector/j, added to the project library and set the class_path for the jdbc connector j